# cv2.namedWindow() doesn't work in virtualenv

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv

When I ran `import cv2;cv2.namedWindow('hello')` in a virtualenv I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 527
```

I tried doing what was suggested there, installed all the dependencies as mentioned in the [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) website. And followed the steps mentioned there to install opencv. I used `WITH_GTK=ON` tag while running `cmake`.

But this error doesn't occur when I use `cv2.namedWindow()`. But error doesn't occur with system python. So I did as it was mentioned in the this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/). I created a soft link of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so` in the virtualenv site-packages.

Still, the error persists. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem. You can try the following:

```
# Symlink your global cv.so file to your virtualenv
cd ~/.virtualenvs/<YOUR_VIRTUALENV>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2
cp cv2.so cv2.so.backup
rm cv2.so
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```